# Simulate data for path model

Tags: simulation, structural-equation-modeling, path-model

How does one simulate data for a path model?  Below is an example path model  with parameters b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, e1, e2 and e3.

I would like to investigate how sample size affects my estimates and what happens to the estimates if a path is added or removed.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a preference for a particular software?

Comment: R code would be great, although it is fine for someone to describe the general strategy without any code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e1`, `e2`, and `e3` are not parameters, these are error terms in the path model. You may need to clarify your understanding of path notation (and may be structural equation modeling in general). These variables do need their parameters, the variances -- I will refer to them as $\psi_k, k=1, 2, 3$. You would also need the variance of `x1` as the model parameter; I will denote it as $\phi_{11}$. These are the standard symbols in SEM notation. With that, we can have

```
    # set up the model parameters and the sample size n
    n <- 100
    b1 <- 1
    b2 <- 0.8
    b3 <- -0.3
    b4 <- 0.5
    b5 <- 0.8
    phi11 <- 1
    psi1 <- 0.64
    psi2 <- 0.49
    psi3 <- 0.81

    # simulate the data
    x1 <- rnorm(n, sd=sqrt( phi11 ) )
    x2 <- b1*x1 + rnorm(n, sd=sqrt(psi1) )
    x3 <- b2*x2 + rnorm(n, sd=sqrt(psi2) )
    y <- b5*x1 + b4*x2 + b3*x3 + rnorm(n, sd=sqrt(psi3) )
```

Comment: I tested your approach on various data. In fact, when it comes to the models analyzed later, it seems that the established path coefficients (b1-b5) in the regression equation are important, and the variances are irrelevant. Why can't they be determined randomly, e.g. psi1 <- runif(1, 0.5, 0.9)?